# Alguien que me puda explicar que hace este codigo?

Tags: java

Alguien que me pueda explicar esto producto proviene de mi modelo y forminventario de mi vista.

```
  producto.setCodigo(this.forminventario.txtCodigo.getText());
  producto.setNombre(this.forminventario.txtNombre.getText());
  producto.setDescripcion(this.forminventario.txtDescripcion.getText());
  producto.setPrecio(Float.parseFloat(this.forminventario.txtPrecio.getText()));
  producto.setStock(Integer.parseInt(this.forminventario.txtStock.getText()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tiene un formulario (forminventario) que tiene varias cajas de texto

1. txtCodigo
2. txtNombre
3. txtDescripcion
4. txtPrecio
5. txtStock

Lo que hace el codigo es sacar la informacion que tienen las cajas de texto y los valores se los asigna a las propiedades del objeto producto

Answer (score 0):

`producto` es un Objeto (o sea que pertenece a una Clase con propiedades y métodos)

`setCodigo`, `setNombre`, `setDescripcion`, `setPrecio`, `setStock` son métodos (funciones) del Ojeto y lo que está en `()` son los parámetros (datos) q se envían a esas funciones para que realicen su propósito.